# how to hide a page from search engine using meta tags?

Tags: asp.net, html, meta-tags

I would like to hide a page from search engine using meta tag. Is there any meta tag for the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

to prevent all robots from indexing the page.

Additionally, you can define rules for specific robots by referencing them by name:

```
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
```

See [google webmasters pages.](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=93710)

Answer (score 0):

You can use META tags though it may not be your best bet. The best resource I can think off for all your options here is: http://www.robotstxt.org/